# Check and Install wget package at time of execution in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I am trying to install the `wget` package using the below code. The objective is to check if a package has already been installed. If not installed, then download and install it automatically at the time of execution of code. The below code works for the `pandas` package but it fails for wget.

```
import pip

# Define function to install missing modules/packages

def install(package):
    pip.main(['install', package])

# Call function and install missing module/package

if __name__ == '__main__':
    install('pandas')
    install('wget')

# Below is the exception message received for wget.

[31mException:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 324, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 380, in prepare_files
    ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 634, in _prepare_file
    abstract_dist.prep_for_dist()
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 129, in prep_for_dist
    self.req_to_install.run_egg_info()
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 439, in run_egg_info
    command_desc='python setup.py egg_info')
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\__init__.py", line 676, in call_subprocess
    line = console_to_str(proc.stdout.readline())
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\pip\compat\__init__.py", line 73, in console_to_str
    return s.decode(sys.__stdout__.encoding)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'encoding'[0m
```

Any idea what could be the problem? I am using Python 3.6.4 with Windows 7 x64 bit OS.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that installing it from outside script is working?
I tried your code and it's working.
I tried to find what happends, and there are two possibilities:

1. You have installed wrong python version (maybe x64 <> x86)? Try to reinstall it
2. You have broken python install, so try to reinstall it anyway.
   It's really strange problem and I dont see clear reason
   Anyway, you should consider using pip3 for python3

Comment: But the code works for `pandas` without any error. So it should be working even for `wget`. Let me try reinstalling python and try again. How do I modify the above code for `pip3`?

Comment: By the way i have python 3.6.4 x64 version installed too.

Comment: hey, does it help?
In this case, pip module is working with python3.x as well as should. Still I think that it's python core issue

Comment: I reinstalled Python 3.6.4 x64 version again and executed the above code. The `pandas` library gets installed successfully but `wget` does not.

Comment: ok, strange. Another idea - could you please try to run this inside virtualenv?

Comment: Well, I am not sure how to run the code inside virtualenv. I am a noob when it comes to Python. What I did notice is that when the program downloads the `wget` package using the above code, it is downloading it as a zip file. While the `pandas` package is not. That could be one reason why its not working for `wget`. Not sure how to fix that.